# How to make a restriction on the addition of tags in the input?

Tags: javascript, html

there is a fully working code. its task is to add tags (text) separated by commas in the input field remembering the choice (the added tag changes color).

everything would be fine, but with this functionality, users can add an unlimited number of tags. how to prevent users from adding more than 4-5 tags? and if you exceed the limit tag will be replaced by another tag?

**html code:**

```
<ul id="aTags">
HTML;
    for ($i=0;$d[$i];$i++) {
      $html .= '<li class="atags-b" onClick="aTags.toggle(this);">'.$d[$i].'</li>';
    }
    $html .= <<<HTML
</ul>
```

**javascript code:**

```
aTags = {
  inputObj : document.getElementById("tags"),
  tagsColl : document.getElementById("aTags").getElementsByTagName("li"),
  array_value : function (arr) {
    var c = 0;
    var tmpArr = new Array ();
    for (key in arr) {
      tmpArr[c] = arr[key];
      ++c;
    }
    return tmpArr;
  },
  toggle : function (e) {
    var iArr = this.inputObj.value.split(',');
    var in_arr = false;
    for (var i in iArr) {

      iArr[i] = iArr[i].replace(/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g, "");
    }
    for (var i=0;i<iArr.length;i++) {

      if (iArr[i] == e.innerHTML) {
        in_arr = true;
        delete iArr[i];
        break;
      }
      else if (iArr[i] == '')
        delete iArr[i];
    }
    if (in_arr === false) {
      iArr.push(e.innerHTML);
    }
    iArr = this.array_value(iArr);
    this.highlight(iArr);
    this.inputObj.value = iArr.join(', ');
  },
  highlight : function (tags) {

    for (var i=0;i < this.tagsColl.length;i++) {

      this.tagsColl[i].className = 'atags-b';
      for (var ii=0;ii<tags.length;ii++) {
        //alert (this.tagsColl[i].innerHTML + ' <> ' + tags[ii]);
        if (this.tagsColl[i].innerHTML == tags[ii]) {
          this.tagsColl[i].className = 'atags-c';
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  iHighlight : function () {

    var iArr = this.inputObj.value.split(',');
    var in_arr = false;
    for (var i in iArr) {

      iArr[i] = iArr[i].replace(/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g, "");
    }
    this.highlight (iArr);
  }
}
```

**click count:**

```
let num = 0, button = document.querySelector('[class=atags-b]');
button.onclick = function () {    
    num++, num > 4 ? this.disabled = true : '';
};
```

Thanks!!

-*Aison*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before `iArr = this.array_value(iArr)`, I would limit the array to 4 elements:

```
iArr = iArr.slice(0, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! xD)